# Pass PDV variables to macro in SAS

Tags: macros, sas

In my program I want to pass all variables from column to macro in SAS. I have code like this:

```
data _null_;
set T.BetterSet;
%test(myCollumn);
run;
```

This is simple macro:

```
%macro test(variable);

data &variable;
set End.DatasetpreparedForAnalisys;
where &variable <= 0;
keep vin3 &variable;
run;

%mend;
```

Unfortunatelly I got error:ERROR: Variable "variable" is not on file End.DatasetpreparedForAnalisys.

How to accomplish this problem? Why passing variables do not work as expected?

Comment: Why are you trying to run one data step inside another? Also, can you clarify what you mean by "pass all variables from a column to a macro?" I don't see how what you've tried so far achieves that.

Comment: Are you trying to pass variable values or variable names?

Comment: It isn't done that way. Use call execute. http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/67912/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n1q1527d51eivsn1ob5hnz0yd1hx.htm

Answer (score 1):

Your code won't work that way since you're issuing data step statements inside another data step. To do that kind of things, you need to set things up differently. Here's how to do it.

First let's generate a dataset called columns (posing as your `T.BetterSet` table), in which we'll insert values `column1`, `column2` and `column5` -- that is, the columns we'd like to see replicated in tables of the same name later on.

```
data columns;
  informat column $32.;
  input column;
  datalines;
column1
column2
column5
;
```

Then we'll generate sample data (posing as your `End.DatasetpreparedForAnalisys` table) containing columns `column1` thru `column5`. Given the content of the `columns` table, only columns 1, 2 and 5 will become standalone tables later on.

```
data sampleData;
  informat column1-column5 8.;
  input column1-column5;
  datalines;
12 -1  2  3  0
-2 -3 -1  0 -3
 0 -4 -5 -2 -9
-1 -5  4  2  0
;
```

Now we declare a macro `%createTable` which will issue all the statements required to create the output datasets for individual columns.

```
%macro createTable(col);
  data &col; 
    set sampleData; 
    where &col <= 0; 
    keep &col; 
  run;
%mend;
```

All is now set up for using the `call execute` routine. Using `call execute` allows you to issue statements in what we could call a "parallel" process; that is, the statements won't be included in the current data step, but rather sent as a standalone chunk of statements to be compiled and executed by SAS. Notice that the '%createTable' macro call is put inside *single quotes*. This is key, as otherwise, you'd run into problems.

```
data _null_;
  set columns;
  call execute(cats('%createTable(', column, ')'));
run;
```

The log now shows:

```
NOTE: There were 3 observations read from the data set WORK.COLUMNS.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.00 seconds
      cpu time            0.00 seconds

NOTE: CALL EXECUTE generated line.
1   + data column1;     set sampleData;     where column1 <= 0;     keep column1;   run;

NOTE: There were 3 observations read from the data set WORK.SAMPLEDATA.
      WHERE column1<=0;
NOTE: The data set WORK.COLUMN1 has 3 observations and 1 variables.
(...)    

2   + data column2;     set sampleData;     where column2 <= 0;     keep column2;   run;

NOTE: There were 4 observations read from the data set WORK.SAMPLEDATA.
      WHERE column2<=0;
NOTE: The data set WORK.COLUMN2 has 4 observations and 1 variables.
(...)

3   + data column5;     set sampleData;     where column5 <= 0;     keep column5;   run;

NOTE: There were 4 observations read from the data set WORK.SAMPLEDATA.
      WHERE column5<=0;
NOTE: The data set WORK.COLUMN5 has 4 observations and 1 variables.
(...)
```

Thus confirming that

- 3 observations were kept from column1 in the new table called column1
- 4 observations were kept form column2 in the new table called column2
- 4 observations were kept from column5 in the new table called column5